# How to collect lots of sensor data to file instead of to memory

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

In the app I am making I need to continuously collect sensor (accelerometer, gyroscope, magnetometer) data over a long period of time and then save this data to a file.

Although I can successfully do this for short periods of time, if I scan for too long I receive an `OutOfMemoryError` which comes from hitting a RAM limit.

So now I am trying to come up with a solution for periodically writing chunks of the sensor data into a file so that I do not hit this error. Is there any "best practice" when it comes to this sort of thing, or perhaps can someone point me in the direction of a post which goes through a solution?

Thanks

*Edit*

I am collecting data as follows:

```
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        try {
            /* Write sensor data to ArrayLists */
            int sensorType = sensorEvent.sensor.getType();
            switch (sensorType) {
                case Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE:
                    gyroData.add(new SensorData3D(sensorEvent.values[0],sensorEvent.values[1],sensorEvent.values[2],sensorEvent.timestamp));
                    break;
                case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
                    accData.add(new SensorData3D(sensorEvent.values[0],sensorEvent.values[1],sensorEvent.values[2],sensorEvent.timestamp));
                    break;
                case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
                    magData.add(new SensorData3D(sensorEvent.values[0],sensorEvent.values[1],sensorEvent.values[2],sensorEvent.timestamp));
                    break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("CRASH", "Failed to write sensor data to array lists");
        }
    }
```

where `gyroData`, `accData`, and `magData` are of the type `ArrayList<SensorData3D>`

Comment: How are you 'collecting' this data, most logging frameworks (log4j, slf4j etc.) have the concept of rolling logs.

Comment: I am writing sensor data to array lists (see my updated post)

Comment: Do you need to persist the data in memory (ie. are you performing operations which combine different reads from the sensors), why can't you just write the data straight to some persistent storage?

Comment: Your RAM will be full, if you keep track of data in realtime in the array list.

It is better to save it to ROM (disk) via database or text file. The save process is only done when new data is different from old data, it will save your ROM (disk).

Comment: I do not perform any operations which combine the reads (other than eventually saving the contents of all of the arrays to the same file). My only concern is: if I am writing the data straight into persistent storage (doing this for many types of sensors) is the device capable of writing the data as fast (or faster) than sensorEvents arrive?

Comment: I'm working on a similar problem but with GPS data. I chose to write the location events to the Android internal database using Room. Then I have code for exporting the data from the database to a file in a couple of formats. It makes the data logging simple as there is no need worry about rotating files. Don't worry about write speed. The SD card can handle it.

Comment: *My only concern is: if I am writing the data straight into persistent storage (doing this for many types of sensors) is the device capable of writing the data as fast (or faster) than sensor events arrive?* 
So how many sensors do you have and how often they are read?

Answer (score 1):

Leaving aside language abstraction data are data, not `ArrayList<SensorWhatever>`. They are sheer numbers. You can do whatever you want with it and can use any data representation you like. More human readable like csv, xml, or binary.
I personally used csv as a way to share data between spreadsheet and processor program as it was really simple to read/write and communicate between these entities.

The simple way could look like this: (let's say `;` is separator, you can use whatever you want - `,` `\t` are the most popular)

```
date;         time;       sensor-id;    data1;    data2; ...;  dataN
2020.01.06;   12.00.00;   gyro;         1.1234;   9.9999;      3.3333
2020.01.06;   12.00.00;   acc;          0.0020;  -0.0987;      9.80665
2020.01.06;   12.00.00;   mag;          11.223;  -34.567;      13.13
2020.01.06;   12.01.00;   gyro;         0.0011;   0.9999;      3.3333
2020.01.06;   12.01.00;   acc;          0.2468;   0.0001;      9.80666
2020.01.06;   12.01.00;   mag;          11.2233;  44.5566;     77.8899
```

And then append it to a log file. You can then create new log every next day or whatever time span you need to not run out of memory and that's it.
Parsing it back is also simple - you read line by line split by separator and interpret strings. Not very complicated.

Or xml, which is kind of fashionable but will make a log much bigger and you will need xml parser to handle it. Both ways. More work, definitely.

If you opt for binary form then you can create structure, fill it with data and then save it as it is in binary form. If your data array is or can be static (with fixed number of fields) then your job is easy, if it's dynamic then you will have lot of problem parsing it back. Then text based option would be more sensible.
Binary database is going to be smaller and easy to parse back if static. Dynamic is a different matter.

Comment: Absolutely no complex structured formats, such as XML or JSON. CSV is trivial to work with in the extremely likely event that the app crashes mid-file. There will be no need to fix anything when recovering the file. Also use gzip to compress the file when writing for the same reason.

Comment: Speaking of compressing. It's little known but most compressors can handle multi member archives. What it means is compressed archive can consist many separate members that are just single archives. For example you can do this: `$ cat 1.log 2.log 3.log | gzip -c > 123.log.gz` or you can compress consecutive logs and append all resulting .gz files into one and it will become valid archive consisting all logs `$ gzip *.log; cat 1.log.gz 2.log.gz 3.log.gz > 123x.log.gz` and it will produce valid archive that can be unpacked. `$ gzip -tv 123x.log.gz` `OK`  It works wits `gzip` `bzip2` `lzip`.

Answer (score 0):

```
gyroData, accData, and magData are of the type ArrayList<SensorData3D>
```

A solution to this problem will be to write the sensor data in different temporary files and append it to them instead of keeping everything in memory. And afterwards just copy the content in the file that you want.

Or you could also stored everything in a database, each time a new sensor event is picked and re read the information when you need to generate the report.

Your problems is that you're using collections to hold data in memory and sooner or later you are going to consume all the available memory. Please check that when you store the information in the files you will empty the collections.